# Animating moving an object within a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, grid

Working on a little web game. Within this, I have a grid made from cells as divs. The player moves cell by cell by appending the player as a child of that div. I can't figure out how to animate the player while it moves such that instead of just "teleporting" when it becomes a child of the other div, is there any way to have the player slide over to the other cell or do I need to reevaluate the fundamental design?

No results from attempting typical CSS animations and transitions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the player character about via appending that element to a new parent, I would recommend putting the character in one large parent div, and using absolute positioning in CSS to move the character:

This would also enable easier animations, letting you use standard CSS transitions!

```
div#character {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    
    transition-property: left, bottom;
    transition-duration: 100ms;
}
```

You could then update the player `.style.left` and `.style.bottom` properties to apply movement.

```
player.style.left = `${xCoord}px`;
player.style.bottom = `${yCoord}px`;
```

(player is the player element)